# "Sorry excuse for a" VS "Sorry excuse of a"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

Which of the two is the correct sentence:

`You are a sorry excuse of a magician`

OR

`You are a sorry excuse for a magician`

If both applies, then what is the difference between the two and when should we use one or the other?

Answer (score 6):

A view of the *[corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20excuse%20for%2C%20sorry%20excuse%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20excuse%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20excuse%20of%3B%2Cc0)* indicates that *sorry excuse for* is more idiomatic.

It seems that the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20excuse%20for%2Csorry%20excuse%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20excuse%20for%3B%2Cc0) from the great island over the sea is more decisive than the one from [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20excuse%20for%2Csorry%20excuse%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20excuse%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20excuse%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Well it is called 'English' you know.

Answer (score 1):

ODO gives, under the definition of [**an excuse for**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/excuse) examples for both *excuse for* and *excuse of*, which would imply that they can be used interchangeably. Although I have to agree, Google Books did give over 33,000 hits for *sorry excuse for a* vs. somewhat less than 2,500 for *sorry excuse of a*.